# double mount point created after using mount manager from ubuntu repossitories

Tags: mountpoint

after I used mount manager from repo, in nautilus was created two mount points for one disk, one works fine, second is simply an icon, when click is getting error:Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

thats link to image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/7cw94

help,any idea? Thanks

Comment: The images linked in the question and in the comment have been lost - dead links now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution that allows you to mount a disk automatically? If that is the case, revert the changes you have made with Mount Manager and do the following:

- Open up Disk Utility and look up the partition device name of the drive you want to have mounted automatically
- Now run:
  `udisks --mount /dev/xxxx` Where xxxx obviously stands for the partition device name. Now, the partition should be mounted.
- Add this command to Startup Applications, which can be found in the session menu in the top-right of your screen.

Comment: when I press revert all changes, I get an error http://www.freeimagehosting.net/vm9nx

Comment: when start again mount manager, nothing is happened