# Hard drive mounted at / , duplicate mounted hard drive after using MountManager

Tags: nautilus, mount, hard-drive, fstab, automount

[possible duplicate post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163753/double-mount-point-created-after-using-mount-manager-from-ubuntu-repossitories)

I'm running 12.04 64bit.  My system is a dual boot for both Ubuntu and Windows7.  Both operating systems are sharing the drive named "Elements".

My volume named "Elements" is a 1TB SATA NTFS hard drive that shows up twice in the side bar in nautilus.  One of the icons is functional and even has the convenient "eject" icon next to it.  Below is a picture of the left menu in Nautilus, with System Monitor->File Systems tab open on top of it.  Can someone advise me about how to get rid of this extra icon?  I think the problem is much more deep-rooted than just a GUI glitch on Nautilus' part.

[image: Nautilus and System Monitor]

The other icon does nothing but spit out the following error when I click on it (image below). This only happened AFTER I tried using Mount Manager to automate mounting the drive at start up. I've already uninstalled Mount Manager, and restarted, but the problem didn't go away.  The hard drive does mount automatically now, so I guess that's cool.  But now, every time I boot up now and open Nautilus, BOTH of these icons appear, one of which is fictitious and useless.

According to the image above and the outputs of several other commands, it appears to be mounted at

/

In which case, no matter where I am in Nautilus when I try to click on that icon, *of course* it will tell me that that drive is in use by another program... *Nautilus*.

I'm afraid of trying to unmount this hard drive (sdb6) because of where it appears to be mounted.  I'm kind of a noob, and I have this gut feeling that tells me trying to unmount a drive at / will destroy my entire file system.  This fear was further strengthened by the output of "$ fsck" at the very bottom of this post.

Error immediately below when that 2nd "Elements" hard drive is clicked in Nautilus:

[image: error message]

```
Unable to mount Elements

Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

It's odd to me that that error message above claims that it's an NTFS volume when everything else tell me that it's an ext4 volume.  The actual hard drive "Elements" is in fact an NTFS volume.

Here's the output of a few commands and configuration files that may be of interest:

$ fuser -a /

```
/:                    2120r  2159rc  2160rc  2172r  2178rc  2180rc  2188r  2191rc  2200rc  2203rc  2205rc  2206r  2211r  2212r  2214r  2220r  2228r  2234rc  2246rc  2249rc  2254rc  2260rc  2261r  2262r  2277rc  2287rc  2291rc  2311rc  2313rc  2332rc  2334rc  2339rc  2343rc  2344rc  2352rc  2372rc  2389rc  2422r  2490r  2496rc  2501rc  2566r  2573rc  2581rc  2589rc  2592r  2603r  2611rc  2613rc  2615rc  2678rc  2927r  2981r  3104rc  4156rc  4196rc  4206rc  4213rc  4240rc  4297rc  5032rc  7609r  7613r  7648r  9593rc 18829r 18833r 19776r
```

$ sudo df -h

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb6                  496G  366G  106G  78% /
udev                       2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                      791M  1.5M  790M   1% /run
none                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                       2.0G  672K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                  932G  312G  620G  34% /media/Elements
/home/solderblob/.Private  496G  366G  106G  78% /home/solderblob
/dev/sdb2                  188G  100G   88G  54% /media/A2B24EACB24E852F
/dev/sdb1                  100M   25M   76M  25% /media/System Reserved
```

$ sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00093cab

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  1953519615   976758784    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e8d9b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          206848   392378768   196085960+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       392380414  1465147391   536383489    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5      1456762880  1465147391     4192256   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       392380416  1448374271   527996928   83  Linux
/dev/sdb7      1448376320  1456758783     4191232   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

$ cat /etc/fstab

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=77039a2a-83d4-47a1-8a8c-a2ec4e4dfd0e / ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=F6549CC4549C88CF /media/Elements ntfs-3g users 0 0
```

$ sudo blkid

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Elements" UUID="F6549CC4549C88CF" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="5CDE130FDE12E156" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="A2B24EACB24E852F" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="77039a2a-83d4-47a1-8a8c-a2ec4e4dfd0e" TYPE="ext4"
```

$ sudo blkid -c /dev/null (appears to be exactly the same as above)

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Elements" UUID="F6549CC4549C88CF" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="5CDE130FDE12E156" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="A2B24EACB24E852F" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="77039a2a-83d4-47a1-8a8c-a2ec4e4dfd0e" TYPE="ext4"
```

$ mount

```
/dev/sdb6 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /media/Elements type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/home/solderblob/.Private on /home/solderblob type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=76a47b0175afa48d,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=391b2d8b155215f7)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/solderblob/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=solderblob)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/A2B24EACB24E852F type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/System Reserved type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

$ ls -a

```
.   A2B24EACB24E852F  Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS amd64
..  Elements          System Reserved
```

$ cat /proc/mounts

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=2013000k,nr_inodes=503250,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=809872k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/77039a2a-83d4-47a1-8a8c-a2ec4e4dfd0e / ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /media/Elements fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/home/solderblob/.Private /home/solderblob ecryptfs rw,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=391b2d8b155215f7,ecryptfs_sig=76a47b0175afa48d,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/solderblob/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sdb2 /media/A2B24EACB24E852F fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/System\040Reserved fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /root/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0 0 0
```

$ fsck

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
/dev/sdb6 is mounted.  


WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.


Do you really want to continue<n>? no

check aborted.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution.

Instead of /etc/fstab reading

```
UUID=F6549CC4549C88CF /media/Elements ntfs-3g users 0 0
```

Change the line to

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/F6549CC4549C88CF /media/Elements ntfs-3g users 0 0
```

Answer (score -1):

It did not work for me. Changing `users` option by `nouser` did. That is,

```
UUID=F6549CC4549C88CF /media/Elements ntfs-3g users 0 0
```