# Everything seems fine, but "Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened."

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, ntfs, fstab

My laptop is set up with separate Win7 and Ubuntu partitions.  I set up my Dropbox to link to the default folder inside the Win7 partition, but it was complaining at start-up about not being able to locate the folder since the drive wasn't mounted yet.  So, I added the following line to my fstab:

```
UUID=627603217602F597   /media/windows   ntfs-3g rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,fmask=0111,dmask=0000   0   0
```

using this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions).   Anyway, it worked, but when I look at the "Devices" section in Home Folder, I see the drives:

```
System Reserved
194 GB Filesystem <-- this is the one I mounted on fstab
61 GB Filesystem <-- just another drive in Win7
2.2 GB Swap Space
windows
```

What's strange is this "windows" drive.  I click it and it gives me the error:

> Unable to mount windows
>
> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.  The volume may be already mounted, or another software may
>   use it which could be identified for example by the help of the
>   'fuser' command.

Just for reference's sake, here's my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=cb40a28f-a046-454a-9a4a-4d8ca76a581c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=708cc5c9-f05b-4fda-8ab9-574e8fed283f none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
#Win7 C-drive Partition  UUID: 627603217602F597
UUID=627603217602F597   /media/windows   ntfs-3g   rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,fmask=0111,dmask=0000   0   0
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/265287/hard-drive-mounted-at-duplicate-mounted-hard-drive-after-using-mountmanager

Answer (score 3):

You need to power **down** Windows. Opening an NTFS partition that went into hibernate will result in the error you're received.

Comment: please also deactivate the Windows 7 fast boot option which basically is nothing else than a hibernation variant.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a hibernation issue at the moment.  I booted into Win7 and checked my Power Options, hibernation was always off.  I also ran powercfg -h off and added remove_hiberfile to my fstab, still to no avail.

Takkat: where can I find this Win 7 fast boot option?

Comment: What do I do if I don't have access to a functioning Windows? (I suddenly can't boot into either ubuntu or windows anymore. I am trying to recover ubuntu from a USB.)